# Docusign Webhook .net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, docusignapi

I am trying to implement Docusign in my application for digital signature. I am using .net core 2.0 for development purpose. I found that the Docusign SDK(https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/) is not compatible with .net core so I tried with the other one (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.Core). The general signature request is working fine but when it comes to Embedded Signing, there is no method available in the SDK(but is available in the original SDK). I am using REST API to complete Embedded signing process and is working fine for now.

Now I want to keep track the status of the document(like when it is delivered, when it is signed by signers and so on). I am configuring webhook to accomplish this task but not getting the webhook object in the webhook endpoint. I referred few documents ("https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-csharp/blob/master/Webhook/Controllers/WebhookController.cs", "https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/webhook-status", 
"https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-msbuild2018-session-thr2605/") to see how a webhook works but looks like none of them is working. In the examples, everyone is getting the webhook object inside request content(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()) but I am getting null at Content.

Can someone help me out to resolve this issue. A sample code or helpful documents(apart from the one I am referring) would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Re: .Net Core SDK support -- we hear you and we're working on it.

Re: webhook setup --

How are you creating the webhook subscription? Via the Administration tool or via the eventNotification object in the Envelopes::create call?

To get going, I'd suggest using the Administration tool. Use the Connect screen to add a webhook notification subscription to your server (your "listener"). Then you'll receive notifications for the events you've indicated an interest in.

Your server must support https and be available on the public internet so DocuSign can send POST requests to it.

Comment: Yes I am using Administration tool. Can you share endpoint configuration for the webhook? I mean what should be the type of endpoint's parameter to receive events? I tried with json string, HttpRequestMessage( as showned in examples) but getting null everytime.

Comment: The event notification messages are sent as XML documents via an HTTPS POST command. Use www.webhookapp.com to see test notifications.